# Generic class addition using querySelectorAll / classList without having to constantly loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, selectors-api

I'm facing the following issue.

Everytime I have to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) with [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), I need to

1. convert the NodeList returned from `Element.querySelectorAll` to an Array
2. perform a forEach to the Array to manipulate each item separately.

jQuery abstracts the above, so I would like to develop a helper method, similar to how jQuery works, that works as such:

```
myhelper('.someClass').classList.add('newClass'); // there are more than 1 .someClass items
myhelper('#id').classList.remove('existingClass');
```

Essentially `myhelper(selector)` should under the hood abstract the points 1+2 above: get the NodeList from querySelectorAll, convert it to an Array, forEach the array and *executed the method that has been given by the user.

PS: to simplify things, it could work for a specific set of native methods: the classList methods and textContent for example.

Comment: You want to implement jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` methods using plain JavaScript, is this correct?

Comment: yep, but I want to abstract looping over the NodeList returned by querySelectorAll everytime..

Comment: @Kaiido it's something I wanna use internally so if the method doesn't exist it should just do nothing or return false.. I can do the array thing easily with call or just with [...nodelist] but I'd like to hide the looping entirely

Comment: I don't see an other way than to rewrite all the properties of Element,  recursively, inside an new object. But you'll still have to define how do the getters work. e.g in your `myhelper('.someClass').classList.add()`  what should happen if you stop at `.classList` ?

Comment: good question. I guess I'll go with a simpler solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first impulse would be to suggest just using jQuery and extend where needed ;)

But to give it a go: if the `my_Helper` function is used as an object, it can buffer the elements and contain functions that use those elements on itself. If my_Helper is called directly, it can be forced to return a new object.
Further the added functionality can return the object itself, so that chaining can be used just as in jquery. A simple example with addClass:

```js
function my_Helper(query){
 if(this.constructor !== my_Helper)
    return new my_Helper(query); //if called directly (not as new()), return a new object
     
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(query);  
  this.addClass = function(className) {
   for(var el of this.elements)
     el.classList.add(className);
   return this; //to be able to use chaining
  }
  return this;
}



my_Helper('.someClass').addClass('newClass').addClass('newClass2'); //2 separate classes to test chaining
```

```css
.newClass{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;  
}

.newClass2{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class= 'someClass'></div>
<div class= 'someClass'></div>
<div class= 'someClass'></div>
```

**edit**, based on the comment, it wouldn't be a problem to add the extra methods manually, but the wish is to make adding individual methods easier without copying the foreach? The below has a general `invoke` function which can be called from outside the objects and helper functions that use this invoke to create the other methods (and also introduces a classList wrapper that simply calls addClass, for making it easier to migrate code)

```js
function my_Helper(query){
 if(this.constructor !== my_Helper)
    return new my_Helper(query); //if called directly (not as new()), return a new object
  
  this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(query);        
  let self = this;
  
  this.invoke = function(property , func, ...pars){
   for(let el of self.elements){    
     if(!func){  //no function given -> property setter
       if(property)
         el[property] = [pars]
      }
      else {
        let p = property ? el[property] : el; //if no property is given, use element itself
        if(!p) continue;

        let fn = p[func];
        if(!fn) continue; //function does not exist on the property or element      
        fn.apply(p,pars);
      }
    }
    return self;
  }
  
  function fn(property, functionName, ...pars){
   return (...pars) => self.invoke(property, functionName, pars);
  }
  
  this.addClass = fn('classList', 'add');
  this.removeClass = fn('classList', 'add');
  this.text = fn('textContent');
  
  this.classList = {add:self.addClass, remove:self.removeClass}; //if classlist has to be used instead of addClass
  
  return this;
}

my_Helper('.someClass').classList.add('newClass').addClass('newClass2').text('aaa');
```

```css
.newClass{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;  
}

.newClass2{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class= 'someClass'></div>
<div class= 'someClass'></div>
<div class= 'someClass'></div>
```

In this basic implementation the invoke expects strings, but it could be easily extended to accept functions as well.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and I'll mark it as correct if nothing else comes up, although what I see is we need to perform the for (or the forEach) for every method .. I was just wondering if it's possible to make the method an argument which would be passed internally and there would be only 1 method in fact for everything
otherwise I guess it's very straightforward

Comment: I see what you mean. implementation would still require to repeat the for each. Added an example to include a more generic approach. It only exposes methods you add yourself, but adding such a method is as easy as `this.text = fn('textContent');` or `this.addClass = fn('classList', 'add');`